# Failed to get Requestcontextholder. getRequestAttributes() in CompletableFuture.runAsync

Tags: java

Is there any way to use `completableFuture.runAsync` to get the `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()`

Comment: How about extracting it outside of completableFuture.runAsync . And then using it in other thread.

Comment: Yes, but how to pass it to the child thread

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we an extract it outside the completableFuture.runAsync and use it.

```
private void extractRequestAttributes() {
    final HttpServletRequest req = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
            .getRequest();

    final String locationStr = req.getHeader("location");

    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        useHeaders(locationStr);

    });

}

private void useHeaders(String locationStr) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}
```

Comment: I have a custom annotation in ```useHeaders``` to obtain the Request, which cannot be passed in this way